# watchOS LTE communication with iPhone app

Tags: swift, apple-watch, cellular-network, watchos-4

I can let my WatchKit app interact with the iPhone app using `WCSession` but this doesn't seem to work over LTE. How can I make that work? Does Apple provide anything for this?

I need to communicate with the app about once per minute.

I found this on Google: https://developer.android.com/wear/images/wear_cloud_node.png from https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html 
Something like this would be nice but doesn't look as instant as `WCSession`

Answer (score 0):

The `WatchConnectivity` framework, which contains `WCSession` uses Bluetooth for communication between an iPhone and an Apple Watch, so it cannot be used for obvious reasons if you'd want to use a watch on LTE.

Currently, there is no direct method for what you are trying to achieve and probably there won't be one in the foreseeable future. The point of the LTE Apple Watch is so that you can access the internet even when your phone is not with you. However, in this situation it wouldn't really make sense to synchronise your data between the two devices until they are physically located close to each other.

You have to upload the data you want to synchronise to a server, from which the iPhone can download it, but I really would advise against this, since it seems to be a waste of resources (both battery capacity and data).